# Database Connection Error after updating from Craft 2 to 3

Tags: database, updating

Good evening all,

I am updating a small site from Craft 2 to 3, and after [following the instructions](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/upgrade.html#preparing-for-the-upgrade) in the documents, I loaded up the backend of my site and was greeted with the install screen.

I know that this typically means that the `DB_TABLE_PREFIX` is improperly set, but I triple-checked and I'm 99% certain that it's correct. I double-checked with my Craft 2, which looks like

```
// The prefix to use when naming tables. This can be no more than 5 characters.
    'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
```

And matched it to my `.env` file:

```
# The prefix that should be added to generated table names (only necessary if multiple things are sharing the same database)
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=craft
```

I also checked for a `craft_info` table, and that is present. The version listed in the version column is 2.9.2, if that makes a difference.

I am unable to login to my admin panel, or view my website now. I get the following when viewing my website:

```
Database Connection Error – craft\errors\DbConnectException
Craft CMS can’t connect to the database with the credentials in config/db.php.
↵
Caused by: Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

-Shad

Answer (score 0):

Does the table prefix value in you `.env` file need to be in quotes? eg

```
DB_TABLE_PREFIX="craft"
```

Comment: However - this sounds to me more like an issue with the credentials. Generally if the table prefix value is wrong Craft will just think it is not installed and try a new installation …

Comment: Thanks for the response. As noted above, the table prefix between Craft 2 and 3 is the same. The prefix wrapped in quotes wasn't the solution.

Comment: In Craft 3 I think you need to add the underscore for the prefix value so Craft 2 is `craft` but for Craft 3 would be `craft_`

Comment: Tried that yesterday, but still no luck. Thanks for checking back in though!

Comment: When the error message reads "can't connect to the database with the credentials" then you have a permissions error. Its not even reaching the db server thus it cannot be a problem with the table prefixes.

In a .env file, you do not need to use quotes unless there are spaces or other "special chars" in your term.